# Grails Page Counter

Tags: grails, hitcounter, grails-services

I need to create a counter for some of the pages.
So I create a domain named Counter :

```
class Counter {
  java.sql.Date date;
  Member member;
  int count;
  int submit;

  //setter and getter...
}
```

Count is for how many times this page opened, and submit is how many time the form is submitted(kind of contact form).

And I created a service named CounterService :

```
class CounterService {
  List counters;

  def load() {
    counters = Counter.findAllByDate(new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
  }

  def increaseCount(Member member) {
    counters.each { 
      if(it.member.id = member.id) it.setCount(it.count + 1);
    }
  }

  //the rest of the code...
}
```

I will save counters to database hourly using Quartz job.

Do You think this counters variable is multithread-safe? Because CounterService will be called in many Controller.
I need to call load before server is started and I don't know where to call it.
Have any suggestion on where I should call load()?
Or perhaps, a better solution for page counter?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `java.sql.Date`? Plain `java.util.Date` can do the same with less code overhead.

I wouldn't use a plain `Map` for this. I would rather use hibernate caching:

```
Counter counter = Counter.findByDate( someDate, [ cache:true ] );
```

so that the objects are kept in cache 5 or 10 minutes long (per default ehcache-settings, don't remember exactly the value)

Another option would be, if you really need ALL counters at once is to use `ConcurrentHashMap` for caching, which DOES enforce the thread-safety:

```
class CounterService {
  ConcurrentHashMap counters
  ....
}
```

Comment: java.util.Date contains time as java.sql.Date does not.
Thanks, I will use ConcurrentHashMap per your suggest. 

But still, where should I call load()?

Comment: Sorry, that should be a List not a Map. I've edited the question to List.

Comment: use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet` for example